# Get all transactions or rows from MySQL since a certain date

Tags: mysql

At the moment, we're working on a project that involves an archaic on board computer (OBC) and a proprietary database. The idea, at the moment, is to use MySQL on the desktop/website, but, when an OBC wants to become up to date, we send it the proprietary database files it needs to come up to date. That is, we don't send it a new copy of the files, just files with the changes and the OBC updates its own instance of the proprietary database.

At the moment, we are using said database on the desktop as well, but, we're trying to move away from it and into MySQL. The problem is that the OBC is so old and so heavily invested into, that we can't move away from its use of the proprietary version.

My question boils down to this: Is there a way to search MySQL for every row that has been altered since a given date (not searching for a date time in a column, but a date time for when this row was altered last), or, would we have to keep track of, on our own, every change (there won't be all that many, at least 1000) made to the database?

Comment: You need to keep track of the modification date on your own.  It is not very hard, and you can use a default timestamp with `on update` to have the database do it automatically for every update (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Thank you. If you want to make that an answer, I'll mark it as preferred.